# download images faster and more efficently

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my app, i repeat an AysnceTask that downloads images from my AWS bucket but they take a little bit to download (1/2 seconds usually) and when I am downloading 10 images it adds up and makes the user experience worse.

My question is: is there a faster way to download images from AWS S3?

Android code:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String PhotoURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/Images/" + productForImages;
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(PhotoURL).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        productColumn = 5;
        productImages[productRow][productColumn] = result;

  }
}
```

Using different services (like AWS), a GitHub, or another library to speed up downloading is possible!

Comment: use Picasso -> http://square.github.io/picasso/ it has caching options and background loading into views. Also, your download speeds will depend on your network, but picasso will do parallel downloads for you

Comment: put this as an answer so i can give you an upvote, i used Glide but ended up with Picasso so you deserve tat least an upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) - Its a easy to use library by

Step 1: Add dependency in gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Step 2: Use in activity

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Picasso handles all the heavy lifting in the background. It also caches the images for faster image retrieval in the future. Also, Picasso does parallel downloads by default.

Comment: @Lazar K glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Try the **Glide** library recommended by google.

It have more features compared to Picasso library.

Add this dependency in your gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
```

Load your image using following code

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("//inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
.into(yourImageView);
```

Reference - https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: not only does this load images 200x faster but it works perfectly with my app! 1+ <3

Comment: @LazarK In picasso any advantage over than Glide??

Comment: For me my app background color was pure white and when I used Glide it added a slight gray background to the image view that made it look ugly. Plus with Picasso if i updated the file on the S3 server it would update on the phone, unlike Glide!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download images faster and more efficiently, then there are methods like multiple connections to download a file (Too much overhead for small files though).

However, the main bottleneck is the users' internet bandwidth. I guess your current implementation is downloading those images every time open your app. This is not efficient. What you can do is that caching the images and checking for update.

For example, when you open your app:

- Load the cached images` (If it is fresh install, then there should also be cached images in your app package)
- check for image update at the background
- If there is an update, download them
- When you finish downloading, update your cache and replace the loaded images if needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use multi threaded downloads: You can make Asynctask's run in parallel with `myTask.execute(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`. This allows more downloads in same time.
2. Make server content delivery faster: Add Amazon cloudfront (a CDN) in front of S3. This speeds up downloads for users.
3. First stream downloading files to a disk cache, then decode into bitmaps of only required resolution. This saves a lot of RAM if you need not show images at full size. Since images are cached, repeated requests for same image will not use network resources.

For #1 and #3, simply use [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/)

Comment: How will downloading the original file save network bandwidth?